# Core data error - returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

My app's core data uses an `NSString` named sectionIdentifier, which I've confirmed through NSLog that it sets. When the data is saved however, `NSLog` shows it set to nil, and despite other items also being set to nil, it shows the error:

```
returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
```

I'm unsure why this is happening. It's set in the same group of code as the other properties, so I don't see why it's 'forgetting' what this property was set to.

EDIT: So here's my error.

First comes where i set it:

```
entry1:
sectionIdentifier = 2001001;
```

Then comes the error:

```
CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) object 
sectionIdentifier = nil;
returned nil value for section name key path 'sectionIdentifier'. Object will be placed in unnamed section
```

Then I do an `NSLog` to check it again:

```
entry2:
sectionIdentifier = 2012007;
```

I have no idea what could be going wrong here, and why it's not recognizing my section identifier.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal test case?